# jquery ui dialog('open') not working when using $(#id .class) as selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My dialog('open') is not opening the dialog window when I use $(#id .class) as selector.  It works fine if I use $(.class) as selector.  I'm needing to use $(#id .class) as selector because there might be more than one .class elements in the dom.

Below is an example show it not working: 
https://jsfiddle.net/b7nth5tm/

```
<style>
.myPopUpDiv {
  display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="myPopUpDiv">
    Why does the chicken crosses the road
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //dialog('open') is not opening the dialog box when using $('#myDiv .myPopUpDiv') as
    //selector.  But it works fine when using $('.myPopUpDiv') as selector. 
    $('#myDiv .myPopUpDiv').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Test',
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
        }
    });
    $('#myDiv .myPopUpDiv').dialog('open');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet, it will search within '#myDiv' for elements with the '.myPopUpDiv' class.

```
$('#myDiv').find('.myPopUpDiv');
```

Here is a jsfiddle with working example

https://jsfiddle.net/hukbvgqx/1/

I binded the jquery to a variable to keep from writing it twice.

Code changes are here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //dialog('open') is not opening the dialog box when using $('#myDiv .myPopUpDiv') as
  //selector.  But it works fine when using $('.myPopUpDiv') as selector. 
  var myDialog = $('#myDiv').find('.myPopUpDiv');
    myDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Test',
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    }
    });

  myDialog.dialog('open');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because jQuery UI changes the DOM when applying the `.dialog()` - function to an element.

You can see that when inspecting your dom. The `div#myDiv` is empty, it doesn't contain the `div.myPopUpDiv` anymore.

JQuery attaches the `div.myPopUpDiv` at the end of the body with additional markup.

This is what your markup looks like after the `dialog` is applied:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-dialog-buttons" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="display: none; outline: 0px; z-index: 1000; position: absolute;">
  <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Test</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div>
  <div class="myPopUpDiv ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block;">
    Why does the chicken crosses the road
  </div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
      <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this to work you can use the `appendTo` - option for the dialog (Note this will only work for jQueryUI Version >= 1.10):

```
$('.myPopUpDiv').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "#myDiv",
    title: 'Test',
    buttons: {
      "Ok": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
    }
  });


  $('#myDiv .myPopUpDiv').dialog('open');
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/phx35ats/)

Comment: this seems off, the OP's question doesn't use #myDiv. I have a working example in my answer. Also, the div.myPopUpDiv has content inside in your dom example.

Comment: @Conceptz the example you posted does in fact not work, there is nothing changed in it. Besides that I never said that `.myPopUpDiv` is empty

Comment: Thanks for the link head's up, I linked the original jsfiddle instead of my edit. link updated and code is inside the answer now. please review. What I should have said is #myDiv isn't relevant to the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks empiric.  I should have realized that.